# Google Script (Sheets) Getlastrow not working as expected

Tags: google-sheets

Thanks in advance! I'm new to script (familiar with VBA) and I can't figure out how to get the correct last row. The variables are completely wrong. I've added comments in the code about the specific parts that are not working. I've tried two different methods to get last row. I basically have a range I need to copy for a daily input to a master file. When the script copies the range, some of the rows may or may not have data. When I run the script again, it treats the whole range as if every row had data. Been working on this for two days and I'm preplexed. I also tried recording a macro, selecting the last cell, pushing control + up, and that is not working either.

Link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gIiChSoz1EMh8UjZxB3kAnsHw0eytPXg9HSnCsN42-c/edit#gid=328424380

```
function morningInputTest () {

var ss           = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var daySheet     = ss.getSheetByName("Day");
var reportSheet  = ss.getSheetByName("Monthly");
var todayDate    = daySheet.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
var expenseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Expense");
var inventorySheet  =ss.getSheetByName("Inventory");
var choreSheet   = ss.getSheetByName("Chores ");

var lookupRangeValues = reportSheet.getRange(2,1,31,1).getDisplayValues();

for(var row in lookupRangeValues){
  if(lookupRangeValues[row][0]==todayDate)
    break;

}
row = +row + 2;

//Copies data from Day shift and pastes in Monthly report
//cash on hand
daySheet.getRange("I2").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("C" + row),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//POS Readout
daySheet.getRange("B3").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("B" + row),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//Waste or free pizza
daySheet.getRange("B5").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("P" + row),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//Dough made
daySheet.getRange("B6").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("N" + row),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//Total expenses NOT itemized
daySheet.getRange("E16").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("K" + row),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);



// Porblem is here. Need to figrue out how to get the actual last row with data. For now it is copying 6 rows down for each row copied, including blank rows
//also need to be able to clear the expenses etc, but I know how to do this. Do it for day and for night. 
//I''ve tried these 3 different methods and none of them are working. 

//This one gives me completely random rows anywhere from 4-30ish
var expLR = expenseSheet.getRange("A999").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRowIndex();
Logger.log(expLR + "Exp");

//This one also gives me seemingly random rows including pasting over existing data
inventorySheet.getRange("B1").activate;
inventorySheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate;
var invLR = expenseSheet.getCurrentCell().getRowIndex() + 1;

//This one works the best, but still leaves gaps (range copied may not always have all rows filled with data, basically it posts the data from A28-D31. If there is one line of data, it still skips 4 rows before pasting the data)
Logger.log(invLR + "INV");
var chrLR = choreSheet.getLastRow()+1;
Logger.log(chrLR + "chr");


//This part also does not work (Exp I added one to get to next blank row, the others I add 1 to the variable, not sure what the best way to do it is as none of then are working at the moment)
//Total expenses itemized
daySheet.getRange("A10:G15").copyTo(expenseSheet.getRange("A" + (+expLR + 1)),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//Total inventory keyed
daySheet.getRange("A19:G24").copyTo(inventorySheet.getRange("A" + (+invLR)),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//Total chores not finished
daySheet.getRange("A28:D31").copyTo(choreSheet.getRange("A" + (+chrLR)),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);


//This all works fine. 
//clears cash on hand
daySheet.getRange("B2:H2").clear({contentsOnly: true});
//clears POS Readout
daySheet.getRange("B3").clear({contentsOnly: true});
//clears Waste or free pizza
daySheet.getRange("B5").clear({contentsOnly: true});
//clears Dough made
daySheet.getRange("B6").clear({contentsOnly: true});
//clears Total expenses itemized
daySheet.getRange("E16").clear({contentsOnly: true});

/*
This is the log reported from the last time I ran the script
10:16:51 PM Notice  Execution started
10:16:52 PM Info    89Exp
10:16:52 PM Info    4INV
10:16:52 PM Info    35chr
10:16:54 PM Notice  Execution completed
*/

}
```

Comment: The sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." See [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual recipe is to use `Sheet.getLastRow()`. If the "blank" rows in your spreadsheet contain formulas, drop-down lists or checkboxes, the method will return the last such row, regardless of whether there is visible content in that row or not.

The function below gets the last row that has visible content.

```
/**
* Gets the position of the last row that has visible content in a column of the sheet.
* When column is undefined, returns the last row that has visible content in any column.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet A sheet in a spreadsheet.
* @param {Number} columnNumber Optional. The 1-indexed position of a column in the sheet.
* @return {Number} The 1-indexed row number of the last row that has visible content.
*/
function getLastRow_(sheet, columnNumber) {
  // version 1.5, written by --Hyde, 4 April 2021
  const values = (
    columnNumber
      ? sheet.getRange(1, columnNumber, sheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1)
      : sheet.getDataRange()
  ).getDisplayValues();
  let row = values.length - 1;
  while (row && !values[row].join('')) row--;
  return row + 1;
}
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! I can't believe it's so complicated in Java and so simple in VBA. Also any tips for best practices is greatly appreciated! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
function getLastDataRow(sheet,col) {
// col in letter
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }              
}
```

and call by this way

```
var lastRow = getLastDataRow(expenseSheet,'A')
```

hope that works (access to your spreadsheet denied)

Comment: I'm not sure why but this function was also wonky. It gave different results (very likely user error on my part...) Thanks for the help anyway! Always good to learn some more code.